# PHP e-mail script

Tags: php, html, html-email

I am trying to make a landing page and collect e-mail addresses from users.

First, I want to save e-mail addresses to a .txt file and I found an AJAX script, but the .txt file remains empty.

I then tried to write a php script to send an e-mail but it did not work.

I put my files on a free host, but cannot to send mails.

Here is my code !

**HTML :**

```
<form name="input" action="email.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
 $to = "my.email.adres@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Send me info on :".$_POST["email"];

mail($to, $subject, $body);
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you configure your `SMTP` settings in your `php.ini`?

Comment: there is no closing <form> tag

Comment: You're also missing a fourth argument `Headers` in your `mail()` function.

Comment: @asprin - the headers argument is optional.

Comment: aspirin thank ok I add headers

imulsion I forgot to copy.

@crush no, how to do that and connect with email.php ?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes it's optional, but I've seen many cases where adding headers solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any output in your log files ?

For the first problem, your text file needs to have write permissions.

Using your FTP client, try changing the text file permissions to `775`, this will allow your scripts to open and write into it.

Here's a little PHP script that will add emails to the file (I changed it to fit your code)

```
<?php

$filename = "emails.txt";

 if($_POST){
    $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $email = substr($email, 0,50);
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $email."\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

Comment: Here, I thought he was having trouble sending emails, not getting them into a text file.

Comment: @user2483089 You're welcome, do you mean this doesn't work for you on localhost ? if not, how did you change the permissions ? and what's your OS ?

Comment: @crush That's true, but he was initially trying to get it into a file, which makes more sense cause simply emailing every single email will be a mess to handle, better to have things in one place.

Comment: @user2483089 can you update your question with the javascript code so we can take a look at it ?

Answer (score 1):

To send emails through a PHP script you need to have an SMTP (email sending) server set up or specify your own SMTP server.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837/1713635)